# min() function not working on date objects in R

Tags: r, date

I have a working solution to this but I'd really like to understand what is causing this issue in the first place. I have a data frame named 'ngx' with a date column named 'DeliveryDate'.

[image]

When I try to find the minimum date of a subset of this data frame:

```
min(ngx[which(ngx$TradedIndexID == 4810), 2])
```

I run into this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

But when I tweak the selection of the 'DeliveryDate' column to:

```
min(ngx[which(ngx$TradedIndexID == 4810), ]$DeliveryDate)
```

It works just fine:

```
[1] "2019-08-01"
```

Does anyone know the underlying issue causing this?

Comment: of which class is your date column?
Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: `class(ngx)` returns `[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"` so that seems to be the root of the problem. Why would it be a tibble if I never defined it as such? @joran

Comment: That means `ngx %>% as.data.frame` could solve the problem. Probably it's a tibble cause you performed an `dplyr` or similar action

Comment: @joran @thomas-fuchs That makes sense, I did an `inner_join` and had no idea that automatically returned a tibble. I mistakenly thought that was only returned when `group_by` or something along those lines was used. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, your data is of type `tibble`. That means you could solve the problem by

1. transforming the data to `data.frame` prior to your calculations: `as.data.frame(ngx)`
2. doing the same in the tidyverse way:
   `ngx %>% filter(TradedIndexID == 4810) %>% summarise(Min = min(DeliveryDate))`

Comment: Thanks @thomas-fuchs, great insight.